# Deleted content hidden by CSS

Tags: bug, deleted-questions

Having 3.4K site rep, deleted content is visible to me, however it is being hidden via CSS: `.deleted-answer` etc. have `display: none;`. The content is still sent over in the HTML. This seems to apply everywhere on this site, but not on other beta sites I've tested.

[image]

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this.

Comment: @michaelpri You're a moderator, I wouldn't expect you to be able to reproduce it.. Now we just need a few sockpuppets with >=2k rep :P

Comment: You see deleted Answers or deleted Questions?